# MapKit JS how to assign mapkit.Coordinates() from variable as digit

Tags: webview, mapkit, filemaker

I am using MapKit JS in Filemaker and can get the coordinates from an input in Filemaker Web View like this.

```
"const punkt = '" & Substitute ( MYMAP::longlat ; ¶ ; ", " ) & "';" & ¶ &
```

The input is e.g.: **59.436549, 10.629371** but I can not get this into mapkit definition. I get the latitude ang longtitude value and make sure it is a digit. But then I need the comma (,).

```
var punkt // this is 59.658985, 10.790869
var punktxy = punkt.split(",");
var x = parseFloat(punktxy[0]);
var x = parseFloat(punktxy[1);
```

When I hardcode it works:

```
new mapkit.Coordinate(59.658985, 10.790869)
```

But I can not get this right. Probably because it is type text when I concatenate it like this:

```
new mapkit.Coordinate(x + ',' + y)
```

This does not work either:

```
new mapkit.Coordinate(x,y)
```

It is probably a string? How do I get the value correct? This is probably a javascript basic question but I am lost here.

Here is my webviewer code that includes the javascript from the text fields. Notice I am putting the x and y values into the javascript. That is why I need 3 js files since I can't seem to get this right: `mapkit.Coordinate(59.658985, 10.790869)`

webviewer:

> // Load your specific implementation of MapKit JS   ""; "const
>   punkt = '" & Substitute ( ARTSFUNN::Lokalitet ; ¶ ; ", " ) & "';" & ¶
>   &     GetLayoutObjectAttribute ( "map1.js" ; "content" ) & ARTSFUNN::Lat
>   & " , " & ARTSFUNN::Long & GetLayoutObjectAttribute ( "map2.js" ;
>   "content" )  & ARTSFUNN::Lat & " , " & ARTSFUNN::Long &
>   GetLayoutObjectAttribute ( "map3.js" ; "content" );   "";

map1.js:

```
mapkit.init({
    authorizationCallback: done => {
        done(
            "<<$$JWT.TOKEN>>"
        );
    }
});
var punktxy = punkt.split(",");
var x = parseFloat(punktxy[0]);
var x = parseFloat(punktxy[1);
var xy = (x + ','+ y); // doesn't work

var MarkerAnnotation = mapkit.MarkerAnnotation,
            clickAnnotation;
var borch = new mapkit.CoordinateRegion(
            new mapkit.Coordinate(
```

map2.js:

```
),
            new mapkit.CoordinateSpan(0.005, 0.005)
);

var map = new mapkit.Map('map');
map.region = borch;
map.mapType = "hybrid";

map.setCenterAnimated(new mapkit.Coordinate(
```

map3.js:

```
), true); 
console.log(map);
```

### update## - just testing and now this seems to work!

Define the Lat and Long in WebViewer:

```
"var x = '" & Substitute ( ARTSFUNN::Lat ; ¶ ; ", " ) & "';" & ¶ &
"var y = '" & Substitute ( ARTSFUNN::Long ; ¶ ; ", " ) & "';" & ¶ &
```

Use the values in the include map.js:

```
var x = parseFloat(x);
var y = parseFloat(y);
// does not work if I don't convert to digit before use!
var bor = new mapkit.CoordinateRegion(
            new mapkit.Coordinate(x,y),
            new mapkit.CoordinateSpan(0.005, 0.005)
);

var map = new mapkit.Map('map');
map.region = bor;
map.mapType = "hybrid";
map.setCenterAnimated(new mapkit.Coordinate(x,y), true);
```

Comment: Can't you calculate directly: `"new mapkit.Coordinate(" & Substitute ( MYMAP::longlat ; ¶ ; ", " ) & ")"`? --- Alternatively, shouldn't `new mapkit.Coordinate(x, y)` work?

Comment: Hi, tried both options but did not work. The only way I could fix it was to add this to webviewer. I split the javascript in 3 files. The first js goes to the "new mapkit.Coordinate(" - then I add the coordinates in FM. Seems like a very dirty way to do it:  `GetLayoutObjectAttribute ( "map1.js" ; "content" ) & ARTSFUNN::Lat & " , " & ARTSFUNN::Long & GetLayoutObjectAttribute ( "map2.js" ; "content" )  & ARTSFUNN::Lat & " , " & ARTSFUNN::Long & GetLayoutObjectAttribute ( "map3.js" ; "content" );`

Comment: I am afraid you have lost me at this point. If your code is typed into the web viewer, then my first suggestion should work. If you're using an external file, then I don't know - not without seeing the file. I am quite sure you don't need the GetLayoutObjectAttribute() function for anything here. You might ask at one of the FM forums, where you can post a file.

Comment: Thanks for your time Michael. I am editing my question to include the code. I must use `GetLayoutObjectAttribute()`to include an external js file. It is much easier to include external js and this is the way I have read it should be done. Or else it is like hard coding all your js into the html page. Very messy. I have a global field that is map.js. If I only could find out how to get the variables into the included map.js. I guess this is also a **MapKit JS** question. Must be some way to construct an array to be inserted.

Comment: If you have a global field with the Javascript code, then why not get it from there directly? Alternatively, if it's in an external file, then read it from there, e.g. through a container field. I don't see how going through the layout is helping. IMHO it should be kept at the data level.

Comment: Sorry I confused you because I myself am confused! The included javscript file(s) is not a global field but a text field added to the layout.

Comment: I still see no reason to use the layout object as an intermediary. -- Re your edit: I am afraid this may be too convoluted. Try to provide a [mcve] that concentrates on the problem at hand.

Comment: I often use this method: the Javascript code will contain `new mapkit.Coordinate(«lat», «lon»)` and the web viewer uses a calculation to substitute the parameters with real values.

Comment: I am not sure why it works now but must have been a typo error. See the updated question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an answer (unless your question is purely about the "as digit" part), but I can't post this much code in a comment.

At the beginning of your question, you used a field named `MYMAP::longlat` which apparently held both coordinates separated by a carriage return. And you used `Substitute()` to replace the return with a comma.

Now you are using two separate fields, `ARTSFUNN::Lat` and `ARTSFUNN::Lon` - yet you're still applying the same `Substitute` operation to both. This does not seem necessary.

More importantly, you're doing:

```
"var x = '" & Substitute ( ARTSFUNN::Lat ; ¶ ; ", " ) & "';" & ¶ &
"var y = '" & Substitute ( ARTSFUNN::Long ; ¶ ; ", " ) & "';" & ¶ &
```

which would produce a result like:

```
var x = '59.436549';
var y = '10.629371';
```

where both variables are clearly strings which you then have to convert to numbers.

I believe you should be doing:

```
"var x = " & ARTSFUNN::Lat & ";¶var y = " & ARTSFUNN::Long & ";¶"
```

to produce:

```
var x = 59.436549;
var y = 10.629371;
```

which can then be used directly by:

```
new mapkit.Coordinate(x,y)
```

---

The same result can be obtained using your original field in:

```
"var x = " & GetValue ( MYMAP::longlat ; 2 ) & ";¶var y = " & GetValue ( MYMAP::longlat ; 1 ) & ";¶"
```

(assuming longitude is the first value listed in the field).

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of the unused variables, was just testing around with different fields. And thanks for your suggestion to get the values as digits without the parseFloat(). I may change the title to include Filemaker since this is really just as much about that as the digit part. I am better at javascript than Filemaker :-)